# AVFoundation Switching Cameras Slow (Connected To Sample Buffer)

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    ...
    setupDevice()
    setupInputOutput()
}
```

View did load starts the setup chain

```
 func setupDevice() {
    let deviceDiscoverySession = AVCaptureDevice.DiscoverySession(deviceTypes: [AVCaptureDevice.DeviceType.builtInWideAngleCamera], mediaType: AVMediaType.video, position: AVCaptureDevice.Position.unspecified)
    let devices = deviceDiscoverySession.devices

    for device in devices {
        if device.position == AVCaptureDevice.Position.back {
            backCamera = device
            setupCorrectFramerate(currentCamera: backCamera!)
        }
        else if device.position == AVCaptureDevice.Position.front {
            frontCamera = device
            setupCorrectFramerate(currentCamera: frontCamera!)
        }
    }
    currentCamera = cameraModeIsBack ? backCamera : frontCamera
}

var deviceInput: AVCaptureDeviceInput?
let videoOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()

func setupInputOutput() {
    do {
        let captureDeviceInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: currentCamera!)
        deviceInput = captureDeviceInput
        captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSession.Preset.hd1280x720

        if captureSession.canAddInput(deviceInput!) {
            captureSession.addInput(deviceInput!)
        }
        videoOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue(label: "sample buffer delegate", attributes: []))
        if captureSession.canAddOutput(videoOutput) {
            captureSession.addOutput(videoOutput)
        }
        captureSession.startRunning()
        if(firstTime){
            setupMetal()
        }
        firstTime = false
        toggleCamerButton.isEnabled = true
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

On a high level I find the device inputs, setup their framerate and setup the capture session, (the buffer output gets processed to a MTKView).

The issue is when I change cameras. It's either snappy and isntant or becomes very slow and freezes for 4-5 seconds before responding.

The logic I use to change the cameras:

```
func updateCameras(){
    DispatchQueue.global().async {
        self.captureSession.stopRunning()
        self.captureSession.removeInput(self.deviceInput!)
        self.currentCamera = self.cameraModeIsBack ? self.backCamera : self.frontCamera
        self.changeCameras()
    }
}


func changeCameras(){
    do {
        let captureDeviceInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: self.currentCamera!)
        self.deviceInput = captureDeviceInput
        if self.captureSession.canAddInput(self.deviceInput!) {
            self.captureSession.addInput(self.deviceInput!)
        }
        self.captureSession.startRunning()
       DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.toggleCamerButton.isEnabled = true
       }
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }

}
```

I've revised it as much as I can. Switching cameras is essentially

1. Stopping the camera session
2. removing the input
3. adding the input
4. starting the session

I have no idea why on earth it's so variable (works perfectly most of the time on my iPhone X while on my iPhone 6 it's always slow).

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the calls to manipulate the cameraSession should be done on the main thread. Try changing `updateCameras()` to use `DispatchQueue.main.async()` instead of  `DispatchQueue.global().async`

Like this:

```
func updateCameras(){
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.captureSession.stopRunning()
        self.captureSession.removeInput(self.deviceInput!)
        self.currentCamera = self.cameraModeIsBack ? self.backCamera : self.frontCamera
        self.changeCameras()
    }
}
```

With that change the call to `DispatchQueue.main.async()` in your `changeCameras()` function should no longer be needed

Comment: The difference is marginal, I get better performance using the background thread on my iPhoneX whereas doing it on the main thread is slightly better on my iPhone6. I'm just wondering if there is some optimization I've forgot to implement.